# Psql connection string dbname parameter apparently not working?

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, psql

I'm trying to use a 3rd party application to run a database migration. The application initiates the connection with the following string (currently passwordless in dev mode):

`host=localhost port=5432 user=myuser dbname=desired_database sslmode=disable`

Despite the dbname parameter, data for the migration ends up in the "myuser" database.

I thought it was a bug with the software, until I tried connecting from the shell as follows:

```
psql "host=localhost port=5432 user=myuser dbname=desired_database sslmode=disable"
```

This brought me into the DB with the same name as the user:

```
myuser=#
```

While in the psql shell, I am still able to connect to the desired database:

```
\c desired_database
You are now connected to database "desired_database" as user "myuser".
desired_database=#
```

Further, I am able to connect directly from the command line as follows:

```
psql -U myuser desired_database
desired_database=#
```

It could be a red-herring, but I believe if I can fix the command-line case, then I will have fixed the issue with my software. For what it's worth, I tried using a super-user to connect with the same results. This is on a Macbook using PSQL 10.4 installed via Homebrew. Everything works fine on my Linux installation. I'm hoping that it's a simple configuration issue.

Comment: I did, actually create users and DB w/ the above names while trying to isolate the problem. I think what is happening is that the library is sending empty password as so: "host=localhost port=5432 user=myuser password= dbname=desired_database sslmode=disable". I missed that before, so it could be considered a bug w/ the library after all. I have to verify that.

Comment: That is a good guess if you are using a password file and not `trust` or `peer`  authentication. Look into the PostgreSQL server log to get a clue.